# Upload images in DataStore using javascript client and google endpoints

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-datastore, google-api-java-client

how can I upload an image to Datastore or Blobstore using javascript and a google endpoints api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at the following threads :

- [Upload file from Javascript to Google Cloud Endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15879865/upload-file-from-javascript-to-google-cloud-endpoint)
- [using blobstore with google cloud endpoint and android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16246734/using-blobstore-with-google-cloud-endpoint-and-android?rq=1)